# How to fix issue with ignoring functions by FragmentNavigator?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I have a 3 Fragments:

1. `MainFragment`
2. `AuthFragment`
3. `ContentFramgment`

When user open application he see `ContentFragment` through `MainFragment`:

1. `MainFragment` check auth state
2. `MainFragment` navigate to `AuthFragment` or `ContentFragment` (depends of auth state).

Issue:

When user tap `logout` button on `ContentFragment`, `AuthManager` call callback in `MainFragment` and `MainFragment` tryes navigate user to `AuthFragment`. It's work untill user not changing device orientation. When user change it - nothing happened and on log I see next one when user tap on `logout` button:

```
2019-04-16 16:51:41.586 29081-29126/online.app I/FragmentNavigator: Ignoring popBackStack() call: FragmentManager has already saved its state
2019-04-16 16:51:41.586 29081-29126/online.app I/FragmentNavigator: Ignoring navigate() call: FragmentManager has already saved its state
```

How I can fix it? I use `1.0.0` version of navigation component.